# Default dbo schema for user from ACL group

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, acl, sql-server-administration, sql-server-authentication

I have following situation

ACL group: domain\aclgroup

user account: domain\account

- user account is a member of the ACL group
- in the sql server ACL group is added to the server logins, mapped to the database with default schema dbo.
- user account is not added to the sql server, I can log by this user account base on that ACL group

So the default schema as I though for the user account should be `dbo`, but it is not.

When I try to create a table without schema like: `CREATE TABLE Test (id int)`, it creates this table in the schema: `[domain\user].Test`

Why it behaves like this and how I can setup it to create a table in `dbo` without explicitly typing `CREATE TABLE dbo.Test`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, user account was not present (deleted?) from server logins but it was present in the database users, with own schema. After deletion of the user, the default schema is dbo